# (pyqgis) Is there a way to disable the progress bar in the processing tool

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

When using processing tool in pyqgis and run, it always creates a progress bar. Is there a way to disable it?

```
processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', _layer, distance_tolerance, 10, False, None)
```

I want to disable it because I get this error when I run my script in travis:

> wrapped C/C++ object of type QProgressBar has been deleted See log for
>   more details
>
> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QProgressBar has been
>   deleted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', _layer, distance_tolerance, 10, False, None, progress=None)
```

Just add "progress = None" and you may be good to go

**Update:** I figured out that you can actually keep track of the process's progress using some kind of dummy progress object. Here's what I have:

```
class DummyProgress(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def error(self, er_msg):
        print er_msg

    def setPercentage(self, percent):
        print str(percent)

    def setText(self, text):
        print text

    def setCommand(self, comd):
        print comd
```

Instantiate an object from this class and pass it as argument to `progress` in your runalg and you will have everything that is happening printed to your console

Comment: that's great and this is working for me as well, can you post related documentation? or where did you find this??

Comment: Sorry, I found this some time ago in a similar question.. seems like i can't find it again. About documentation, I've been looking for it too without success. the only link I can send you is the [user manual](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html) but it does not help much