# How to use progress.setPercentage() in PyQGIS processing

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2.18

I try to use `progress.setPercentage(i/pages)` in PyQGIS processing.

I tried to give integers, floats between 0 to 100.

Example:

```
percent = 33
percent = 33.3
percent = 0.33

progress.setPercentage(percent)
```

Nothing appears in the progress bar and no crash.

`progress.setText("Blablaba")` is working

The script

```
##Extract then join WS  and attributes=name
##Scripts utilisateur=group
##B1_column_position=number 1
##SQL_query_file=file
##File_name=string extrWS_geom.shp
# https://medspx.fr/blog/Qgis/verify_oracle_geoalgorithm/  to install cx_oracle

import cx_Oracle
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
import os
import datetime

...

for i in range(pages):

    progress.setPercentage(i/pages*100)
    print("pagination : " + str(i))
    rage = i*1000
    print(rage)
    attributesList1000 = convertedDatesattributesList[rage:rage+1000]
    geometriesLayer = getGeoms(writeGeomquery(attributesList1000))
    for attr in attributesList1000 :
        writer.addFeature(joinGeombyID_WS(attr, geometriesLayer))

...
```

QGIS documentation:

> If your algorithm takes a long time to process, it is a good idea to
>   inform the user. You have a global named progress available, with two
>   possible methods: setText(text) and setPercentage(percent) to modify
>   the progress text and the progress bar.
>
> Several examples are provided. Please check them to see real examples
>   of how to create algorithms using the processing framework classes.
>   You can right-click on any script algorithm and select Edit script to
>   edit its code or just to see it.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [QGIS Processing Progress](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110524/qgis-processing-progress)

Comment: Maybe it should be `progress.setValue(percent)`?

Comment: No it returns an error : 
**AlgorithmDialog' object has no attribute 'setValue' See log for more details**

Comment: Please, can you try using `progress.setPercentage((i/float(pages))*100)`?

Comment: Yes it works. @mgri. Add you answer for votes. ;)

Comment: @jlSta I'm glad it worked. I just added my solution as an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is related to the division operation. You can try to use:

```
progress.setPercentage((i/float(pages))*100)
```

instead of:

```
progress.setPercentage(i/pages*100)
```