# How to show a moving progress bar in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, progress

I want to sum values and during do it, a window shows progress percentage.
I write below code but when I run it in qgis python console, qgis crashes. what is error in this code?

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *

def progdialog(progress):
    dialog = QProgressDialog()
    dialog.setWindowTitle("Progress")
    dialog.setLabelText("text")

    bar = QProgressBar(dialog)
    bar.setTextVisible(True)
    bar.setValue(progress)
    dialog.setBar(bar)
    dialog.setMinimumWidth(300)
    dialog.show()

def calc(x, y):
    sum = 0
    progress = 0
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            k = i + j
            sum =+ k
            progress =+1
            progdialog(progress)
    print sum

calc(10000, 2000)
```

Comment: Have a look here, you might find your answer : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/111405/25139

Comment: I think you may need to do something to set your progress in percentage unit - just my instinct saying that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there's a few minor issues:

- You're using `=+` which means you're setting it to equal a positive value. I think you meant to use `+=` which adds and sets the new value to the variable.
- Within your two `for` loops, you are calling the `progdialog()` function `x*y` times. Each time it is **recreating** the progress dialog and bar instead of updating it. I'm guessing this cause QGIS to crash.
- As [@gisnside](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25139/gisnside) mentioned, you need to set the progress values accordingly.

---

You could try using the following which calls the `progdialog` function once and returns the reference to the progress dialog and bar:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QProgressDialog, QProgressBar

def progdialog(progress):
    dialog = QProgressDialog()
    dialog.setWindowTitle("Progress")
    dialog.setLabelText("text")
    bar = QProgressBar(dialog)
    bar.setTextVisible(True)
    bar.setValue(progress)
    dialog.setBar(bar)
    dialog.setMinimumWidth(300)
    dialog.show()
    return dialog, bar

def calc(x, y):
    dialog, bar = progdialog(0)
    bar.setValue(0)
    bar.setMaximum(100)
    sum = 0
    progress = 0
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            k = i + j
            sum += k
        i += 1
        progress = (float(i) / float(x)) * 100
        bar.setValue(progress)
    print sum

calc(10000, 2000)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @nickan - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)